# Oracle update million records from XML file

Tags: oracle, shell, unix, sql-loader

Gurus ,

I have reporting shell script on LINUX platform,Oracle 12c database which does the following.

- Read the Error XML file created in last 24 hrs( mtime)from the unix directory path
- Sed unwanted text like '
- Fetch each row and column using `cut -d ";" -f $X`
- Prepare `update statement`
- execute update statement after processing each file to set the error
  code.

In UAT I received , 400 files , each file have 20,000 rows. which means, update statement will be prepared 400X20,000 times and each statement will be executed.

The issues I see are:

- Unable to log/handle update errors in order to debug or rerun them.
- it is taking lot of time even though we have indexes.

What is the best way to handle such situation?

I have following thought in mind: Instead of creating update statements, use sqlldr to load to temp table and execute update/merge two tables. I'm not sure about performance of executing 400 sqlldrs.any idea?

Is there a better way to handle ? in terms of error handling and process.

Comment: Are you using sed and cut to parse XML into relational text? Why aren't you using [the DB's XML tools](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb01int.htm) to do that? As another alternative to SQL\*Loader you could use an external table. Either will be faster than parsing and running individual update statements. What kinds of errors are you expecting?

Comment: What's your definition of "better" and "best"? How would you know if one solution is better than another? It's not clear what your question is exactly.

Comment: @AlexPoole yes I'm using sed,cut/ awk to create relational text. I'm doing this because, each XML file have different fields in different locations. I didnt want to create multiple temp tables for each kind. if i could pull the required data which is common for all types and load in to common temp table template, i could avoid having multiple logics. Is DB XML faster in parsing ?

Comment: @mustaccio, best i meant in overall solution, in terms of experience in handling such situations. better", i meant in terms of the alternative option is gave.

Comment: @AlexPoole i just noticed that XDB is not installed.I know i can get it installed but have to get necessary approval and valid reasons to get it installed.

Comment: By "relational text", do you mean that you are creating a file full of update statements?

Comment: @DavidAldridge Yes that's what I did initially, but then i change the process to create a temporary files with comma separated values and load to temp tables using sqlldr. I tried AlexPoole Suggestion but it doesnt seems to good with the kind of XML data I have.